# Shell Scripting Error

Tags: powershell

```
$path='C:\Desktop\f'
$r=Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.deb

for($i=0; $i -lt $r.Count; $i++){
do { 
  get-content $r[$i]
```

this is a pseudo code of the program I am trying to write the path I am trying to fetch is on desktop in a folder called f

but `$r[$i]` is different for example

the error as is

```
get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\Desktop\6747.deb' because it does not exist.
At C:\Desktop\deb.ps1:7 char:3
+   get-content $r[$i]| % {
```

even though my path is in desktop folder f
why is it just going till dekstop and not any further

the `deb.ps1` file is present on the desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$r` is a list of objects, not file names. Try this instead:

```
Get-Content $r[$i].FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier is to use a pipe:

```
$r[i] | get-content
```

or to simplify the whole script:

```
$path='C:\Desktop\f'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.deb | get-content
```